# iOS: Simple way to manage REST end points

Tags: ios, swift, rest, configuration

Our REST based application can be used for testing on multiple internal environments each with a different REST end point.   Is there a simple way to set up environment level configuration within an iOS (Swift 3) app?  I've seen a few approaches but they all seem pretty involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using https://github.com/theappbusiness/ConfigGenerator:

> A command line tool to auto-generate configuration file code, for use
>   in Xcode projects. The configen tool is used to auto-generate
>   configuration code from a property list. It is intended to create the
>   kind of configuration needed for external URLs or API keys used by
>   your app. Currently supports both Swift and Objective-C code
>   generation.

Answer (score 2):

This is my approach of doing things when we have multiple end points. I used to make a `ConfigurationManager` class something like this

> **Swift 3.0 code**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

let kEnvironmentsPlist:NSString? = "Environments"
let kConfigurationKey:NSString? = "ActiveConfiguration"
let kAPIEndpointKey:NSString? = "APIEndPoint"
let kLoggingEnabledKey:NSString? = "LoggingEnabled"
let kAnalyticsTrackingEnabled:NSString? = "AnalyticsTrackingEnabled"

class ConfigurationManager:NSObject {

    var environment : NSDictionary?

    //Singleton Method

    static let sharedInstance: ConfigurationManager = {
        let instance = ConfigurationManager()
        // setup code
        return instance
    }()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        initialize()
    }

    // Private method

    func initialize ()   {

        var environments: NSDictionary?
        if let envsPlistPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Environments", ofType: "plist") {
            environments = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: envsPlistPath)
        }
        self.environment = environments!.object(forKey: currentConfiguration()) as? NSDictionary
        if self.environment == nil {
            assertionFailure(NSLocalizedString("Unable to load application configuration", comment: "Unable to load application configuration"))
        }
    }

    // CurrentConfiguration

    func currentConfiguration () -> String   {
        let configuration = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?[kConfigurationKey! as String] as? String
        return configuration!
    }

    // APIEndpoint

    func APIEndpoint () -> String  {
        let configuration = self.environment![kAPIEndpointKey!]
        return (configuration)! as! String
    }

    // isLoggingEnabled

    func isLoggingEnabled () -> Bool  {

        let configuration = self.environment![kLoggingEnabledKey!]
        return (configuration)! as! Bool
    }

    // isAnalyticsTrackingEnabled

    func isAnalyticsTrackingEnabled () -> String  {

        let configuration = self.environment![kAnalyticsTrackingEnabled!]
        return (configuration)! as! String
    }

    func applicationName()->String{
        let bundleDict = Bundle.main.infoDictionary! as NSDictionary
        return bundleDict.object(forKey: "CFBundleName") as! String
    }
}
```

In **Project**--> **Info** Add some new configurations as per your need.

[image]

I have added **Staging** and **QA** as extra endpoints.Generally I use to make Staging as Release config and QA as Debug. So it will look like:

[image]

Now go to **Targets** -> **Build Settings** and add a **User Defined Setting**

[image]

Give the name of the user defined like **ACTIVE_CONFIGURATION**.

[image]

Add a key named `ActiveConfiguration` in `info.plist` with a variable name as `$(ACTIVE_CONFIGURATION)` same as given in **User Defined Settings** with a **$** in the beginning. We gave the name of key as `ActiveConfiguration` because we are using the same name in our `ConfigurationManager.swift` class for `kConfigurationKey`.

```
let kConfigurationKey:NSString? = "ActiveConfiguration"
```

You can define as per your naming convention.

It will look like:

[image]

Now in the `ConfigurationManager` class I am getting a path for `Environments.plist` file.

I will just make a `Environments.plist` file like this:

[image]

The actual description source of this file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Development</key>
    <dict>
        <key>APIEndPoint</key>
        <string>https://dev</string>
        <key>LoggingEnabled</key>
        <true/>
        <key>AnalyticsTrackingEnabled</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Flurry</key>
        <dict>
            <key>FlurryApplicationID</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>FlurryApplicationSecret</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
        <key>Facebook</key>
        <dict>
            <key>FacebookAppID</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>FacebookAppSecret</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>QA</key>
    <dict>
        <key>APIEndPoint</key>
        <string>https://qa</string>
        <key>LoggingEnabled</key>
        <true/>
        <key>AnalyticsTrackingEnabled</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Flurry</key>
        <dict>
            <key>FlurryApplicationID</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>FlurryApplicationSecret</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
        <key>Facebook</key>
        <dict>
            <key>FacebookAppID</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>FacebookAppSecret</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>Staging</key>
    <dict>
        <key>APIEndPoint</key>
        <string>https://staging</string>
        <key>LoggingEnabled</key>
        <false/>
        <key>AnalyticsTrackingEnabled</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Flurry</key>
        <dict>
            <key>FlurryApplicationID</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>FlurryApplicationSecret</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
        <key>Facebook</key>
        <dict>
            <key>FacebookAppID</key>
            <string>840474532726958</string>
            <key>FacebookAppSecret</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>Production</key>
    <dict>
        <key>APIEndPoint</key>
        <string>https://production</string>
        <key>LoggingEnabled</key>
        <true/>
        <key>AnalyticsTrackingEnabled</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Flurry</key>
        <dict>
            <key>FlurryApplicationID</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>FlurryApplicationSecret</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
        <key>Facebook</key>
        <dict>
            <key>FacebookAppID</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>FacebookAppSecret</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

We are now good to go. Now you have to just call

```
ConfigurationManager.sharedInstance.APIEndpoint()
```

for your respective end points.
Now you just have to change the schemes from Edit Schemes and you are done and change the **Build Configuration** in **info**.

[image]

[image]

This not only manages **API End Points** but also other things like whether to enable analytics or tracking for the respective end point or different ids of Facebook for different end points.

Answer (score 1):

As Zac Kwan suggested, you can use different schemes to accomplish this, but you don't necessarily have to create a different configuration as well. Each scheme can specify unique environment variables. Then, access them from Swift:

```
let prodURL = "http://api.com"
let baseURL = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["BASE_URL"] ?? prodURL
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that creating different Scheme and Configuration for your project works best. My setup is as follow:

I usually have 3 different scheme, `MyApp-dev`, `MyApp-staging` and `MyApp`.

Each of the `scheme` i created `User-Defined-Attribute` to have different string appending to my `Bundle Display Name`. So it can concurrently appear on my iOS device as `MyApp-d`, `MyApp-s` and `MyApp`. Each also have its own `Bundle ID` Then I create custom flags for each of them.

So in my `Routes.swift` files i have something like this at the top:

```
#if PRODUCTION
    static let hostName = "http://production.com/api/v1/"
#elseif STAGING
    static let hostName = "http://staging.com/api/v1/"
#else
    static let hostName = "http://development.com/api/v1/"
#endif
```

There is quite a few ways in how to update different hostname. But ultimately creating different Scheme and Configuration is always the first step.

Here is a few links that might help you get started:

https://medium.com/@danielgalasko/change-your-api-endpoint-environment-using-xcode-configurations-in-swift-c1ad2722200e#.o6nhic3pf

http://limlab.io/swift/2016/02/22/xcode-working-with-multiple-environments.html