# how to make variable each build in XCode

Tags: swift, xcode

I built six build in XCode.

I have two targets, and made a configuration called 'release', 'staging', 'debug'
Then, I want make different variables each build.

Now I set it up with

```
#if
#elseif
#else
#endif
```

But I'm looking for a better way than them.

What's the best way?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want different REST endpoints for different configurations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a REST API Endpoint management process for different configurations (Debug,Staging,QA,Production).
Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40230742/2545465).

The way you mentioned is also another way by using `#if` and `#elseif`.

```
#if
#elseif
#else
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for different plist files for different configurations.

Depending on current configuration, respective plist file to be used.

Reference:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-quick-tip-managing-configurations-with-ease--mobile-18324