# How can I create a unique variable for each build in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I have six builds like

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        manifestPlaceholders = [appVersion: ""];
    }
    staging {
        applicationIdSuffix '.staging'
        versionNameSuffix '-staging'
        manifestPlaceholders = [appVersion: "-stg"];
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        versionNameSuffix '-debug'
        manifestPlaceholders = [appVersion: "-debug"];
    }
}
productFlavors {
    panel {
        versionCode 2
        versionName '1.1'
        applicationIdSuffix '.panel'
        manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "exampleapp-panel"];
    }
    admin {
        manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "exampleapp-admin"];
    }
}
```

I want to change each function or variable for each build.
I can use it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40230742/2545465) in XCode, but I have not found a way in Android studio.

Can I make a setting file using in AndroidStudio like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like following for each build/product flavor.

```
        buildConfigField "boolean", "VALUE_KEY", "true"
        resValue "string", "my_string", "Some string"
```

The first can be accessed in your code as BuildConfig.VALUE_KEY, the 2nd is written to strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
productFlavors {
    pro {
        minSdkVersion 15
        applicationId 'com.myapps'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        targetSdkVersion 23
        resValue "string", "app_name", "myapps"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEV", "false"
    }
    dev {
        minSdkVersion 15
        applicationId 'com.myapps.dev'
        targetSdkVersion 23
        resValue "string", "app_name", "myapps 1.2"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEV", "true"
    }
}
```